# WPF clipping border when moving with mouse

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get some code to work that allows a UIElement to be moved using the mouse.
It works except when the UI Element being dragged is moved to within its height or width from the bottom or right of its containing window it gets clipped. After altering the size of the UIElement being dragged its obvious that the clipping region is proportional to the width or height relative to the right or bottom.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="" Height="500" Width="500" MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="500">
    <Grid>
       <Border BorderBrush="Black" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp"
            MouseMove="UIElement_OnMouseMove" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFDE1B1B"            
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="100"    
            Margin="84,82,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool moving = false;
    Point _previous = new Point();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var l = e.Source as UIElement;
        if (l != null && l.IsMouseDirectlyOver)
        {
            _previous = e.GetPosition(null);
            l.CaptureMouse();
            moving = true;
        }
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Width + ", " + this.Height);

        var l = e.Source as UIElement;
        if (l != null)
        {
            l.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            moving = false;
        }
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (moving)
        {
            var p = e.GetPosition(null);

            if (_previous != default(Point))
            {
                var ui = sender as FrameworkElement;

                var deltaX = p.X - _previous.X;
                var deltaY = p.Y - _previous.Y;

                ui.Margin = new Thickness(
                    Math.Max(ui.Margin.Left + deltaX, 0),
                    Math.Max(ui.Margin.Top + deltaY, 0),
                    ui.Width,
                    ui.Height);

                Title = ui.Margin.ToString();
            }
            _previous = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently no idea why the border is being clipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you specifically set the margin to the right edge to be `ui.Width`, and the margin to the bottom edge to be `ui.Height`. Set them both as 0 (the default value) and the element is not clipped.

```
ui.Margin = new Thickness(
                Math.Max(ui.Margin.Left + deltaX, 0),
                Math.Max(ui.Margin.Top + deltaY, 0),
                0, //ui.Width,
                0); //ui.Height);
```